# CardViews in ListView: Card clicks not executing click listener

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

I am implementing a ListView of CardViews.
However, when I click, I can see the card being clicked, but does not execute the listener.
All the cards are rendered properly and clicking, but not executing the listener function.

**Activity.java**

```
final List<String> deviceStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        deviceStringList.add("Device 1");
        deviceStringList.add("Device 2");
        deviceStringList.add("Device 3");
        deviceStringList.add("Device 4");

        String[] deviceStringArray = deviceStringList.toArray(new String[deviceStringList.size()]);
        DevicesListViewAdapter cardListAdapter = new DevicesListViewAdapter(this, deviceStringArray);
        ListView deviceCardsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceCardsListView);
        deviceCardsListView.setAdapter(cardListAdapter);

        final List<String> finalDeviceList = deviceStringList;
        deviceCardsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalDeviceList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class DevicesListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] deviceName;

    public DevicesListViewAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, String[] deviceName) {
        super(context, R.layout.device_card_layout, deviceName);

        this.context = context;
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_card_layout, null, true);

        Button cardBtn = (Button) cardView.findViewById(R.id.cardButton);
        cardBtn.setText(deviceName[position]);

        return cardView;
    }
}
```

**CardView layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cardButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_device_btn"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Try to use `onClickListener` on your `cardView`

Comment: Please check out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Remove this:

```
deviceCardsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalDeviceList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
});
```

and write like this:

```
cardBtn.setOnClickListener(...) {
    onClick() {

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Inside your Adapter as shown below:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_card_layout, null, true);

    Button cardBtn = (Button) cardView.findViewById(R.id.cardButton);
    cardBtn.setText(deviceName[position]);

    .......(Write Here)

    return cardView;
}
```

Hope it helps. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the onItemClickListener, try giving the on click listener either to the main LinearLayout or to the CardView. OnItemClick doesn't work for the listview which is focusable or having the clickable item. Hence defining the click listener for the item inside the list should solve the problem.

For your reference

```
  LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_of_LL);
                    mainView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.show();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks Yashaswi. I would also like to have the card clickable on the whole card but when I tried to set the click listener on the LL, it did not work.

Comment: try giving the click listener to the cardview @madu

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering your onClick listeners for each view in the adapter and then communicating back to the parent activity through an interface? For example, in your adapter class create an interface

```
public interface CardListener {
    void onSelected();
}
```

in your adapter, define a private variable to store a reference of an implementation of the interface to be passed in via a setter method. Something like:

```
private CardListener listener;
```

define a setter in the adapter

```
public void setListener(CardListener listener) { this.listener = listener; }
```

then when binding your data in the getView method do the following

```
cardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(listener != null) { listener.onSelected(); }
    }
});
```

Finally, in your activity you can set the callback definition like so

```
adapter.setListener(new CardListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelected() { // Do something here };
});
```

This will allow you to define many custom click actions in case you need to do something with individual click actions on different view in the card view down the road. It also allows you to pass any adapter data back and forth and allow you to separate adapter logic from the activity logic in a more compartmentalized manner. Hope this helps.

For more information check this helpful resource: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#attaching-event-handlers-within-adapter

Answer (score 0):

android:clickable="true" change to android:clickable="false"

if you r use listview.setonclick then cardview clickable must be false